# modal com dados de tabelas diferentes do mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, bootstrap-3

Olá! estou enfrentando um problema com um modal dinâmico. Em uma página Index, o usuário irá selecionar um estado e uma cidade e será encaminhado para a página dos modais; Nessa página será apresentado as Filiais da cidade escolhida(código ainda não criado) e todos os estados brasileiros em uma navbar, os estados que uma ou mais cidades possuírem uma filial(estes estados possuem `status = 0`) chamará um modal com estas cidades (estas cidades possuem `status = 0`) , já os outros estados (que não possuem nenhuma cidade com filial/ `status = 1`) será encaminhado a uma página de erro.

**Procurando no banco as informações de acordo com o estado e a cidade escolhida na página anterior**

```
<?php
   $query3 = "select * from estados where estado_id = ".$_GET['estados']."";
   $dt3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
   $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($dt3);
?>
```

**Criando um navbar com todos os estados**

```
<nav id="nav2" class="navbar navbar-default">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#estados">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="estados">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <?php 
            $query4 = "select * from estados";
            $dt4 = mysqli_query($conn, $query4);

            while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($dt4)){
                $nome2 = $row4['nome'];
                $estado_id2 = $row4['estado_id'];
                $active = "";
                $caret = "class=\"caret\"";

                 if ($estado_id2 == $row3['estado_id']){
                     $active = "class=\"active\"";
                 };

                if($row4['status']>0){
                    echo "<li $active><a href='erro.php'>$nome2</a></li>";
                }else{
                    echo "<li $active ><a href='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal".$estado_id2."'>$nome2<span $caret></span></a></li>";
               };
        ?>
      </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
```

**Modal**

```
 <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal<?php echo $estado_id2 ?>">"
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content desktop-hide">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    &times;
                </button> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="panel-info">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <?php
                                $query6 = "SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE estado_id = ".$estado_id2." AND status = 0";
                                $dt6 = mysqli_query($conn, $query6);

                                while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($dt6)){
                                    $nome3 = $row6['nome'];
                                    echo "<li><a href=''>$nome3</a></li>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Fechar
                </button>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content mobile-hide">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="panel-info">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <?php
                                $query6mob = "SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE estado_id = ".$estado_id2." AND status = 0";
                                $dt6mob = mysqli_query($conn, $query5);

                                while($row6mob = mysqli_fetch_array($dt6mob)){
                                    $nome3mob = $row6mob['nome'];
                                    echo "<li><a href=''>$nome3mob</a></li>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Fechar
                </button>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php };?>
```

**O Problema:**
Por algum motivo, que é o que eu quero descobrir, os links dos Estados estão desconfigurados, eram para estar que nem o Estado do Acre como mostra a imagem!
[image: Estou utilizando Bootstrap versão 3.0]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como esses links aparecem no código-fonte do HTML?

Comment: Perceba também que faltou fechar o `while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($dt4)){`.

Comment: @Sam, agora fechei o ` while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($dt4)){ ` depois de fechar o ultimo modal, mas mesmo assim está do mesmo jeito!

Comment: @Sam  Em relação ao código fonte, eu editei novamente a pergunta, confira a segunda imagem!

Comment: o `data-target='#modal".$estado_id2."'` não estava chamando corretamente o modal, devido à varíavel `estado_id2` estivesse sendo fechada antes da `</ul> </div> </nav>`, para arrumar isso, fechei o `while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($dt4))` depois dos modais.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui arrumar! Fechei `</ul></div></nav>` depois que fechei o `while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($dt4))`